# Go Channels - Pushing to a channel stops execution

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I'm trying to create a command line quiz, where users would be asked question after question until they either finish the final question, or they are timed out.

I wanted to use channels so I could learn how to use them properly, and I've hit a blocker, so to speak.

The idea is for correctAnswersCh to start with 0, and after every correct answer, it will increment by 1.

The quiz always stops at line 3 of the quiz() function, after I put zero into the channel.

I've added some code below, but the full code is here:
https://play.golang.org/p/vzRCTc7MpIK

```
func main() {
    questions, err := getCsvData()
    var limit = time.Duration(3)


    flag.Parse()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    quizComplete := make(chan bool)
    correctAnswersCh := make(chan int)
    go quiz(quizComplete, questions, correctAnswersCh)

    select {
    case <-time.After(limit*time.Second):
        fmt.Println("Timed Out")
    }
    fmt.Printf("Correct Answers: %v\n", <-correctAnswersCh)
}

func quiz(quizComplete chan bool, questions [][]string, correctAnswersCh chan int) {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    correctAnswersCh <- 0
    // execution stops here.  0 is added to correctAnswersCh, then the quiz func stops
    for _, question := range questions {

        fmt.Print(question[0], "= ")
        answer, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

        if strings.TrimSpace(answer) == question[1] {
            cA := <-correctAnswersCh
            cA++
            correctAnswersCh <- cA
        }
    }
    quizComplete <- true
}
```

Comment: Channel is blocked when zero is added because channel is unbuffered. Even if you write a value to it, it will block there on that line until channel is read somewhere else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `correctAnswersCh` channel is unbuffered, so sending anything on it blocks until there is someone receiving from it. And since your `main()` function only receives from it after the timeout, your app is blocked until then.

One simple workaround is to give 1 buffer to the channel:

```
correctAnswersCh := make(chan int, 1)
```

Although this is some weird usage of channels. If your intention is to create a concurrency safe counter, use an aotmic counter, e.g. [`atomic.AddInt32()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#AddInt32). Another option is to use a mutex ([`sync.Mutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex) or [`sync.RWMutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#RWMutex)) to protect a resource (variable) when accessed concurrently from multiple goroutines.